# Proving two matrices have the same eigenvalues when one is Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a $A$ Hermitian matrix that can be written as $A = B + iC$ where $i$ is an imaginary number. Also, $B$ and $C$ are $n$ dim real-value matrices. Now, there is a matrix,

$$
  D = \begin{pmatrix} B & -C \\ C & B \end{pmatrix}
$$

Here, I would like to prove that $A$ and $D$ have the same eigenvalues in this case.

I have first attempted to prove that D is actually a symmetric matrix as below,

$$
  \begin{align*}
     A = A^* = \bar{A}^T \\
     A = B + iC = (B - iC)^T, B = B^T, C = -C^T \\
     D = \begin{pmatrix} B & -C \\ C & B \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} B^T & C^T \\ -C^T & B^T \end{pmatrix} = D^T
  \end{align*}
$$

However, I have no clue about writing the relation of eigenvalues with respect to matrices $A$ and $D$. Can anyone give me some suggestions for the next step? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, for any two real square matrices $B$ and $C$ of the same size, each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B+iC$ gives rise to a pair of eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$ of $D=\pmatrix{B&-C\\ C&B}$, because
\begin{aligned}
&\pmatrix{I&iI\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{B&-C\\ C&B}\pmatrix{I&iI\\ 0&I}^{-1}\\
&=\pmatrix{B+iC&-C+iB\\ C&B}\pmatrix{I&-iI\\ 0&I}\\
&=\pmatrix{B+iC&0\\ C&B-iC}\\
&=\pmatrix{B+iC&0\\ C&\overline{B+iC}}.\\
\end{aligned}
When $B+iC$ is Hermitian, its eigenvalues are real. Hence $\lambda=\overline{\lambda}$ in the discussion above, meaning that the spectrum of $D$ is precisely two copies of the spectrum of $B+iC$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is helpful, it looks like the central idea is row operations. I also referred some ideas from other people, and I think your solution is the most concise one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ such that $Av = \lambda v$. We have $Bv + iCv = \lambda v$. Then $(v, -i v)$ is an eigenvector of $D$ with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$:
\begin{align}
&\begin{pmatrix}B & -C\\ C & B\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v\\-iv\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}Bv+iCv\\Cv - iBv\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda v\\-i\lambda v\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}v\\-iv\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Taking complex conjugate of the eigenvalue equation for $A$, we have $Bv^* - iCv^* = \lambda v^*$. Similarly, you can check $(v^*, iv^*)$ is also an eigenvector of $D$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. These two eigenvectors are linearly independent, therefore, for every eigenvalue of $A$, you can find two eigenvectors of $D$ with the same eigenvalue. In other words, $A$ and $D$ have the same set of eigenvalues, but $D$ has two copies of the same set of eigenvalues, as mentioned in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730839) too.

Comment: Hi, may I ask how did you get the eigenvector of D? I am not certain how to derive them when facing a block matrix. It looks like $Av = v, (A - )v = 0, (B+iC-)v = 0$, but I am not sure how to derive afterward.

Comment: @user1551 thanks for the catch! I made a mistake when checking linear independence through inner product. Amended the original answer.

Comment: @Sonamu do you mean you're not familiar with block matrix operation? Basically when you partition your matrix into blocks, matrix multiplication works as if each of the blocks are numbers (of course you don't have multiplicative commutativity). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication for more information. You can also check my steps on showing $(v, -iv)$ is an eigenvector for $D$: $B$ and $C$ are matrices but they are treated as if they are numbers in a $2\times 2$ matrix. Same for $v$, it is an array but treated as if it is a number in a 2 dimensional vector